# Android drag and drop ImageView with no option to drag again

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview, android-linearlayout

In my app i have 10 linear layouts that are used as drop zone to ImageView.
I want to drag the ImageView (card game) to its drop zone.
This part working fine.
The problem is, I want to allow the user to make only one move - and then to cancel the DragListener so that the ImageView will be stuck to its drop zone.
any ideas?
here's a bit from my code:

```
    private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    SetDragListner();

        if (TouchTheStart != false) {
            if (CountTheTime < 20) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    CountCards();
                    if(ReachedDestination==false){
                    Random = getRandom();
                    getCard();
                    }
                    ReachedDestination=true;
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }
        return true;

    }
}

class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // Do nothing
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setBackground(enterShape);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackground(normalShape);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);
            Cards.remove(Random);
            CountTheTime++;
            ReachedDestination=false;
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            v.setBackground(normalShape);
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
Boolean allow=true;
```

and in onTouch add

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(allow==true){
        //here you do everything and where you want to disallow the other onTouch add allow= false;
    }
    //add your return statement here
}
```